# How to update keyname in JSON obj from angular smart table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to angular and JSON.
I have a JSON file and I want to update this file from HTML table.

My json is

```
{
  "graph": {
    "nodes" : [
      {
        "Node": {
          "size": "2",
          "color": "#A5ABB6",
          "bordercolor": "#9AA1AC",
          "borderwidth": "1.5",
          "textcolor": "#000000",
          "fontsize": "8",
          "caption": "Name"
        },
        "Slot": {
          "size": "2",
          "color": "#25c4e8",
          "bordercolor": "#1a8ca5",
          "borderwidth": "1.5",
          "textcolor": "#000000",
          "fontsize": "8",
          "caption": "name"
        }
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

When I add new row in table or edit existing row from table and click on save new values are get reflected in JSON, but I am unable to update key name like "Node" "slot". Values of "size", "Color" get changed.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat=" (key,gp) in graphConfig.graph.nodes[0]" class="editable-row">
    <td>
        <span editable-text="key" e-name="key" e-form="rowform"
              data-e-style="max-width:50px" e-required>
            {{key}}
        </span>
    </td>
     <td>
     <span editable-text="gp.size" e-name="size" e-form="rowform" 
        data-e-style="max-width:50px" e-required>
                {{gp.size}}
             </span>
        </td>
```

In HTML, gp gives all values like size, color, bordercolor etc.
key gives "Node"," Slot".

In html--  
                    
                        Save
                    
                 -------in controller--

```
$scope.saveInJsonFile = function (data) {
        var newKey=data.key;
        console.log(newKey);
        console.log("OBJ",data);

        commonFactory.saveJsonObj($scope.graphConfig).then(function (asyncCastData) {
        });
    }
```

Plz reply...